# I need to fix aliasing in text and logos in Media Encoder

Tags: anti-aliasing, adobe-premiere, adobe-after-effects

I hope someone can help.

I need to export an animated logo from AE and then import it to Premiere to add at the end of an edited video and then finally export to .MP4. I'm exporting the logo in AE as Quicktime and then I play that there is no aliasing but when I export the final video in premiere I get bad aliasing in .MP4 and Quicktime 422.

My only option seems to be to export the whole video and audio through AE which would be such a pain and not what it's designed for. I need a way to cleanly get my Quicktime AE logo exported through either Premiere or Media Encoder and I'm totally stuck.

I'd be really grateful if anyone has a solution!

Comment: Can you provide us with some screen caps to help us see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I was running into the exact same issue today.  Files looked fine out of AE but aliasing when imported/ exported in Premiere.  Tried different export codecs from AE, all had issues (ProRes was worse, Animation looked better for some reason).  These were gradient shape layer lower third backgrounds created in AE (bright yellow/ green gradient).  Workaround was to send them back to AE as a linked comp from my Premiere timeline and then they looked fine in Premiere.  Stupid Adobe bug.  (Another designer was creating the gfx and delivering quicktimes to me, which is why I didn't just use AE linked comps to begin with)